# How to decompose and smooth tags from a BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**How to decompose and smooth tags from a BeautifulSoup object?**

***Not from string.***

From a soup, to a soup without going to a string.

The [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) suggest using the `smooth()` method to eliminate undesired blank spaces. Can you show me?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
dml = '''<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>LOOSE TEXT
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    <div>MORE TEXT</div>
    <b></b>
    <i></i> # COMMENT
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(dml, features='lxml')
def strip_empty_tags(soup:BeautifulSoup):
    for item in soup.find_all():
        if not item.get_text(strip=True):
            item.decompose()
            soup.smooth()  # How to .smooth()?
    return soup

strip_empty_tags(soup)
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>LOOSE TEXT


<div>MORE TEXT</div>

 # COMMENT
</body>
</html>
```

The `decompose()` and `extract()` methods make undesired blank spaces/blank lines appear. I want to get rid of them. But no I do not want to `''.join([string for string in string_list])`.

There are precedents to this question, in particular: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286777/remove-lines-getting-empty-after-beautifulsoup-decompose), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263932/python-how-to-remove-empty-line-in-html). But all suggestions involve converting the BeautifulSoup object to a string. I can do that, I'm already doing that, but I don't want to do that.

This site has many other references to BeautifulSoup and "remove empty spaces", but most of them deal with situations where the text content has empty spaces *to begin with*. In my situation, the empty spaces are a by-product of BeautifulSoup's decompose/extract methods. I'd like to remove them immediately after they are created in the loop.

I am using the `'lxml'` parser and don't plan to change, unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract empty tags with `tag.replace_with('')`, then do `parent.smooth()` and replace all empty characters at the end of the string with `re.sub`.

For example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dml = '''<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>LOOSE TEXT
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    <div>MORE TEXT</div>
    <b></b>
    <i></i> # COMMENT
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(dml, features='lxml')
def strip_empty_tags(soup:BeautifulSoup):
    for item in soup.find_all():
        if not item.get_text(strip=True):
            p = item.parent
            item.replace_with('')
            p.smooth()
            for c in p.find_all(text=True):
                c.replace_with(re.sub(r'\s{2,}$', '\n', c))
    return soup


print( strip_empty_tags(soup) )
```

Prints:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>LOOSE TEXT
<div>MORE TEXT</div>
 # COMMENT
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. However, all the action is in `re.sub`. I don't see that `item.parent.smooth()` does anything. If I remove the two lines starting with `for c in p.find_all...`, then all the spaces are still there. As I wrote in my question, I know how to remove spaces from the strings. I have even patched the `extract()` function to remove spaces. But the `BeautifulSoup` experts told me that the `smooth()` method could do it. Unfortunately, I don't see that. My question is: **Can you remove the spaces from the BeautifulSoup objects without converting to string?**

Comment: @PatrickT The [`smooth()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#smooth) function doesn't remove spaces - it just joins [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring)s together - that happens when you do `extract()`, `decompose()` or in this case `.replace_with()`. So you dont have `[<tag>[some string], [another string 1], [another string 2], </tag>]` but `[<tag>[some string + another string 1 + another string 2]</tag>]`. You need to still strip the empty spaces somehow - in this case with `re.sub()`.

Comment: I see, so there's no "built-in" function in the BeautifulSoup suite to remove the spaces? I must have misunderstood a comment to that effect. When I patched `extract()` to remove blank lines, I was told that `smooth()` was the suitable method. I thought it meant there was a way to use `smooth()` for that purpose. But now I'm starting to feel that what was meant is that removing spaces should be done by a patched version of  `smooth()`. So thanks, and let me accept your answer!